# How to distribute objects in Blend for Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, blend

Visual Studio's Blend gives users the option to align selected objects via the Objects>Align menu, but there seems to be no options for distributing objects (like you would do in Expression Design: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295118.aspx or Photoshop).

Am I missing something or there's simply no options for distributing selected objects in Blend?

Comment: Align basically is distribute, is there something specific you're looking to accomplish? I would strongly recommend not building a great reliance on the WYSIWYG side of blend and learn some of the basics of xaml, it's actually a pretty neat markup.

Comment: Aligning objects is not the same thing as distributing objects. Distributing allows creation of even spaces between 3 or more objects, not sure how aligning objects can help with that.

Comment: Might as well [start learning](http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html) how to use more than buttons amigo. Cheers

Comment: I still fail to see how that is relevant to my necessity.

Aligning: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294822.aspx
Distributing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295118.aspx

^ That's what I'm interested in, but in Blend, not in Expression Design.
Blend has the aligning feature, but lacks the distributing option.

Comment: Dude if you fail to see the relevance of learning how to do things like Grid's or StackPanel's etc, in the XAML that is produced from your design surface to distribute objects, I can't help ya. Blend is Design's big brother, it's not just point and click if you want to produce xaml that won't be laughed at when you hand it off.

Comment: I don't care about any other aspects. I am interested in being able to evenly distribute objects on a grid at any given time, and apparently Blend doesn't have it.

Comment: wow, sure thing buddy. Good luck with that.